# Did my rights get violated

Tags: united-states

I was sitting outside of the Sprint store today while waiting on my step daughter to come out.while I was sitting there I noticed that a guy that worked at the store came out looked at my car while talking on the phone he then went back into the store.about 10 minutes later two officers walked up to my car and asked me to cut off my vehicle and come inside only to find out that the store call the police because they have had people to come in and purchase phone and never pay the bill and that he felt that my step daughter came in to apply for service to do the same thing,she had qualified for service and payed for her devices at this point.so the store manager went on to say that people has been getting phones from them to sale on the black market and refused my step daughter service and asked for us not to come back to the store are we will be arrested for trespassing, I'm confused because I hadn't been in the store until the officer asked me to come in.I just feel violated

Comment: Clearly it was not a pleasant experience but in which part do you think your rights were violated? The fact that it was a police officer asking you to come inside? What if it was the store manager who had asked you to do that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description of the facts is vague enough that we can't offer an informed judgment, but to remedy this, I will paraphrase your account of the facts (you can decide whether this is what you were trying to say).

> I was sitting outside of the Sprint store today waiting for my step
>   daughter to come out. While waiting, two police officers walked up to
>   my car and asked me to turn off my vehicle and come inside. When I
>   voluntarily went inside, the store staff said that they called the
>   police because they had had some sort of problems with people applying
>   for service and absconding with the phone to resell on the black
>   market, and they thought that was part of some such criminal plan.
>   Because of that, they refused to give her a phone or service contract.
>   But then they also told us to never come back, threatening arrest for
>   trespassing. I have never been in that store before. Were my rights
>   violated?

No, neither by the police nor by the manager. The police, or the store manager, can legally request you to come in for a conversation: what matters most is whether you were forced to come in against your will. By your report, you were not, so your rights were not violated. The police are irrelevant to the remainder of the question.

What remains is whether your rights were violated because the manager told you to go away and never come back under pain of prosecution. The store is private property, meaning that the owner has wide latitude to grant or deny permission to enter. If they hate pink hair and your hair is pink, they can legally "ban" you. If they suspect you of involvement in a criminal activity, that can most certainly legally ban you. That does not mean that it was a righteous or justified decision on their part, or a good business choice, but it *is* their legal right. So, no, your rights were not violated.

Comment: They can  ban you UNLESS you are member of a protected class or the ban is discriminatory.

Comment: @Hilmar - don't you mean " member of a protected class **and** the ban is discriminatory", rather than 'or'? Simply being a member of a protected class doesn't make you 'ban proof'...